# What do I need to destroy the world?

Tags: code-golf, physics

The [gravitational binding energy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_binding_energy) of a planet is the amount of energy required to separate every tiny piece of it so that no piece will orbit or collide with another piece. For a uniform sphere, Wikipedia gives this formula:

$$E = \frac{3GM^2}{5R}$$

Where G is the gravitational constant (6.672e-11 m<sup>3</sup>•kg<sup>-1</sup>•s<sup>-2</sup>), M is mass, and R is the radius.

I *could* make this challenge about merely calculating this in Joules (kg•m<sup>2</sup>•s<sup>-2</sup>), but… that would be *boring*. And besides, not everyone understands Joules.

So instead, let's convert it into the following units:

- Kilotons of TNT (4.184 trillion Joules, shorthand `kilotons`)
- Hiroshima nuclear weapons (62.76 trillion Joules, shorthand `nukes`)
- Hostess™ Twinkies (560,000 Joules, shorthand `twinkies`)
- Kilowatt-hours (exactly 3.6 million Joules, shorthand `kWh`)
- Kilograms of mass-energy (1 kg mass-energy = 299,792,458<sup>2</sup> Joules, shorthand `kg`)

So, take in the following input:

- mass in kilograms
- radius in meters
- one of six distinct inputs representing the unit to use

And output the binding energy in the specified units. Append the shorthand unit to the end of the output.

## Rules

- The shorthand for Joules is `J`.
- Arbitrary whitespace is allowed, as long as it doesn't split the shorthand unit or the number.
- Scientific notation is allowed, in whatever format your language uses.
- You only need 4 significant figures. Floating points are *highly* recommended.
- Blah blah shortest answer in bytes.

## Test Cases

Generated with [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-EqcIhiNm9kXbXmsQzstkAhGFf_KQJJZay8Al6Zft9c).

```
Mass (kg)   Radius (m)  J           kilotons    nukes       twinkies    kWh         kg
3.302E+23   2440000     1.789E+30   4.275E+17   2.850E+16   3.194E+24   4.969E+23   1.990E+13
4.869E+24   6052000     1.568E+32   3.748E+19   2.499E+18   2.800E+26   4.356E+25   1.745E+15
5.974E+24   6371000     2.242E+32   5.360E+19   3.573E+18   4.004E+26   6.229E+25   2.495E+15
6.419E+23   3390000     4.866E+30   1.163E+18   7.753E+16   8.689E+24   1.352E+24   5.414E+13
1.899E+27   69911000    2.065E+36   4.935E+23   3.290E+22   3.687E+30   5.736E+29   2.298E+19
5.685E+26   58232000    2.222E+35   5.310E+22   3.540E+21   3.968E+29   6.172E+28   2.472E+18
8.683E+25   25360000    1.190E+34   2.845E+21   1.896E+20   2.125E+28   3.306E+27   1.324E+17
1.024E+26   24620000    1.705E+34   4.075E+21   2.717E+20   3.045E+28   4.736E+27   1.897E+17
1.311E+22   1186000     5.801E+27   1.387E+15   9.244E+13   1.036E+22   1.611E+21   6.455E+10
1.989E+30   696300000   2.274E+41   5.436E+28   3.624E+27   4.062E+35   6.318E+34   2.531E+24
7.350E+22   1737000     1.245E+29   2.976E+16   1.984E+15   2.223E+23   3.458E+22   1.385E+12
```

---

Inspired by [Powering the Death Star with Twinkies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8LIDFGawDU) by Scott Manley.

Comment: what do you mean by "default to joules"? does that mean that the output unit will not always be given in the input?

Comment: also, I love how there's actually a name for the amount of energy needed to completely annihilate a thing :P

Comment: can we take the output unit as any of 6 distinct inputs? otherwise it's a cumbersome I/O format and those are discouraged

Comment: @HyperNeutrino sure, but you still need the shorthand in the output.

Comment: @StephenLeppik "_one of six distinct inputs representing the unit to use_" - can those distinct inputs be 4.184, 62.76, etc?

Comment: @ngn Sure, but you still need the shorthand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>56</s> 54 bytes

Takes input as `unit, radius, mass`

```
6n56•G*•x619+•Oć•4°z)•1¡‡•S°*"Wwigu"I1èkè*2498T>°P/*¹J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fLM/U7FHDInctIFFhZmipDaT9j7QDSZNDG6o0gbThoYWPGoBoUfChDVpK4eWZ6aVKnoaHV2QfXqFlZGJpEWJ3aEOAvtahnV7//@eVZqcWcxmZmBgAAZexnrGBUaqRMQA)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to *Erik the outgolfer* (base 255 encode `4184` and `6276`).

Answer (score 17):

## JavaScript (ES6), 78 bytes

Takes input as 3 distinct variables `(mass, radius, unit)`.

```js
(m,r,u)=>m*m/r/[8987e9,56,6276e6,,4184e5,1e-4,360][parseInt(u,30)%7]/2498e11+u
```

#### Test cases

The following snippet runs all test cases in the provided spreadsheet.

```js
let f=

(m,r,u)=>m*m/r/[8987e9,56,6276e6,,4184e5,1e-4,360][parseInt(u,30)%7]/2498e11+u

console.log(
  [
    '3.302e+23 2440000   1.789e+30 4.275e+17 2.850e+16 3.194e+24 4.969e+23 1.990e+13',
    '4.869e+24 6052000   1.568e+32 3.748e+19 2.499e+18 2.800e+26 4.356e+25 1.745e+15',
    '5.974e+24 6371000   2.242e+32 5.360e+19 3.573e+18 4.004e+26 6.229e+25 2.495e+15',
    '6.419e+23 3390000   4.866e+30 1.163e+18 7.753e+16 8.689e+24 1.352e+24 5.414e+13',
    '1.899e+27 69911000  2.065e+36 4.935e+23 3.290e+22 3.687e+30 5.736e+29 2.298e+19',
    '5.685e+26 58232000  2.222e+35 5.310e+22 3.540e+21 3.968e+29 6.172e+28 2.472e+18',
    '8.683e+25 25360000  1.190e+34 2.845e+21 1.896e+20 2.125e+28 3.306e+27 1.324e+17',
    '1.024e+26 24620000  1.705e+34 4.075e+21 2.717e+20 3.045e+28 4.736e+27 1.897e+17',
    '1.311e+22 1186000   5.801e+27 1.387e+15 9.244e+13 1.036e+22 1.611e+21 6.455e+10',
    '1.989e+30 696300000 2.274e+41 5.436e+28 3.624e+27 4.062e+35 6.318e+34 2.531e+24',
    '7.350e+22 1737000   1.245e+29 2.976e+16 1.984e+15 2.223e+23 3.458e+22 1.385e+12'
  ]
  .map((l, n) => {
    [m, r, ...res] = l.match(/\S+/g).map(Number);

    return 'Test case #' + -~n + ' -> ' + (
      ['J', 'kilotons', 'nukes', 'twinkies', 'kWh', 'kg']
      .every((u, i) => +(+f(m, r, u).split(u).join``).toExponential(3) === +res[i])
      ? 'OK' : 'FAIL'
    )
  })
)
```

#### How?

This is quite similar to [@ColeraSu's C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149186/58563), with a JS-friendly hash function that works on the whole unit string.

```
Unit       | Parsed as (*) | Base-30 -> Dec. | mod 7
-----------+---------------+-----------------+------
"J"        | "j"           | 19              | 5        (*):
"kilotons" | "kilotons"    | 451052545318    | 4          Because we're parsing as Base-30,
"nukes"    | "n"           | 23              | 2          characters [u-z] (and anything
"twinkies" | "t"           | 29              | 1          after them) are simply ignored.
"kWh"      | "k"           | 20              | 6
"kg"       | "kg"          | 616             | 0
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 78 bytes

```
²×⁽LÐ÷ȷ14÷⁴÷5÷⁵ị“¤Fðẏẏż“?A⁺ẏẏż“¬ŀż“8Ƙż“¡uþ³⁾ẉṿÆ“¡’¤;⁵ị“ÞṠlT“¡ṁæ-“;ØḲ“ȧ¹“ṫD“}»¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QpsPTHzXu9Tk84fD2E9sNTQ5vf9S45fB2UxC99eHu7kcNcw4tcTu84eGufiA6ugfIt3d81LgLiX9ozdEGMMPi2AyIwMLSw/sObX7UuO/hrs6HO/cfbgMLPmqYeWiJNdzYw/Me7lyQEwKWeriz8fAyXSDT@vCMhzs2ARknlh/aCaQe7lztAqRqD@0@tOT////GesapRsb/jfRMTFLN/hsCAA)

Stuff to do with strings isn't really Jelly's type of challenge...

-7 bytes thanks to user202729 (thanks for helping me not get beaten by JavaScript :D)

Comment: Yeah, now you're tied with JS and still not on top either.

Comment: @StephenLeppik At least I'm not getting beaten :D and shush 05AB1E is inherently better at string challenges :P

Answer (score 6):

## C, 113 bytes

Hash the second character, using the trailing `'\0'` of `"J"`. Inline array in C is used.

Note we need to multiply the second `M` last, or it will overflow to `inf`.

```c
f(m,r,c)float m,r;char*c;{printf("%e%s",m/r/(float[]){1e-4,360,6276e6,8987e9,56,4184e5}[c[1]%36%7]/2498e11*m,c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc27CoMwGIbh3auQgBDb30MORsW5S2@ggzhIiAfUKBrpIF67lW4dCn7TOzzwSa@W8jgqPMAM0q36sTT22Zlsyvkms22aW20qjBzlLAiGYA7wF@WFuxHlcWAiBEFjoQQkaRKrFCIBnCRcRXsuc1I4TDhxEVCeJoqQ23DeZPsxlK3GrrVZdoWZz0L6uFMGlPPwnA/oidxsWs2C0Rn/UNf2oxn1csXqtVOXoHm3uuuv2e7VXGL1j9qPDw)

Comment: +1. Not sure if possible, but f(m,r,char*c)float m,r{…} would save some bytes. Also, the semicolon after printf is optional

Comment: @xanoetux Which compiler do you use? Both don't work on my machine though.

Comment: I'm using GCC. Untested, but I'm quite sure about the last semicolon. (will test later)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>153 71</s> 69 bytes

```apl
op←{⍺,⍨40032E¯15÷÷/8987E13 36E5 6276E10 56E4 4184E9 1['gWuw '⍳⊃1↓⍺]⍵⍺⍺⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZNPSsNAHIX3niK7KGic/5k5wGxm1Z0LcSEotaQ0BVuKiCvBhVARxDu4cyFScGlvkovUNJk00/gChcDvK48vL7zL6fjk6u5ynA83xcv7YFA8vYpNPi0f98Xy57hYfghCOLO/n1SuV@vVqTY6tZRHXFkZKZYqS0kklRWRoFpYE9HzeHg2X0Rxsfwqnh9p8fRWJl0Uy@/yUf2@HzabOBvGh0yU4YRE@fSIJ9wyfhA7eM1G43yWT24hnMyza0xmi9EkG/XA7OwG3Q8qM0Uk83eRaGUsE6EFxN4DstYEJ29dIHH47i15Sj2RiUlF1xLhxhKxwBImV5aIOHyvLTk3TccqEdR0vijE3hKy1hInby0hcfjuuzSGNi9AE21KlO6VCXnTJoRBnTi86hMi1wNqV6kZZ7uylZaWqdAVc@@KYevaE751xcj1gNqVSa6aynWJypHJvUFD3mwawmDWOLxaNkSuB/x3pQlhotMr5sC1hdg1CO@6tsj1gNqVUq12hFNqGQtVIfamkLWiOHnrCYnD92ZVipP2DYw2lpP9WcE/7HYFaTgsnF8vCzLXR3yvKU89SRMuSbdXhJteEQt6hclVr4g4eP8D)

Thanks to @Adám for absolutely crushing my old answer into this one.
Thanks to @ngn for 2 bytes.

This 'function' is actually an operator called `op`.
All the values for the measurement units were transformed to scientific notation.

#### How it works:

```apl
{⍺,⍨40032E¯15÷÷/8987E13 36E5 6276E10 56E4 4184E9 1['gWuw '⍳⊃1↓⍺]⍵⍺⍺⍵}
                                                             1↓⍺         ⍝ take the measurement unit without the first letter (because it is ambiguous)
                                                            ⊃            ⍝ picks the first element returned by 
                                                           ⍳             ⍝ Dyadic ⍳ota, which finds the index of
                                                  'gWuw '                ⍝ each of these characters
                                                 [             ]         ⍝ square brackets indicate the index
               8987E13 36E5 6276E10 56E4 4184E9 1                        ⍝ of the element of this vector (1-indexed) which will be used as the divisor for
            ÷/                                                  ⍵⍺⍺⍵     ⍝ dividing by the left operand (⍺⍺) and the right argument squared.
    40032E¯15÷                                                           ⍝ then divide this number by the result
 ⍺,⍨                                                                     ⍝ and append the measurement unit
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>112</s> <s>106</s> <s>108</s> 101 Bytes

```
lambda m,r,u:str(40032e-19*m*m/r/{'':1e-4,'i':4184e5,'u':6276e6,'w':56,'W':360,'g':8987e9}[u[1:2]])+u
```

Pretty straight forward. Uses Python's `e` notation. Uses a dict that distinguishes unit based on the second letter and divides by the corrosponding value. `u[1:2]` is basically `u[1]`, expect it returns `''` instead of an error (which I only learned now). Then applies the formula with a few simplifications.

edit: down to 106 thanks to totallyhuman, back to 108 because of new nukes value and down to 101 thanks to Colera Su.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc1NDoIwEEDhvacwbAZwlP5RYBIv4AVcIAuNRYkWSWlDjPHsyAVcvy95w9vfX72c2/1pfp7t5XpeW3QYaPQuVoxJYbY8T21qM5d9AIgjdECKl8pUCAFIi0IbzhAmoFwbhXAEktrkCDcgUVVFJVRepqn41qHmJJom2YR5cF3v4zaWO2mERKGWGWMYHaIkWf2Lfur6R2fGxcw/)

Answer (score 3):

## Excel (Office 365), <s>106</s> <s>101</s> 97 bytes

Assuming cell `A1` is the mass, `A2` is the radius, and `B1` is the unit, written as the shorthand for the output.

```
=40032E-19*A1^2/(A2*SWITCH(MID(B1,2,1),"u",6276E6,"w",56,"W",360,"g",89876E8,"i",4184E5,1E-4))&B1
```

## Excel, 130 bytes

Old-fashioned Excel doesn't have the `SWITCH` function, so you have

```
=40032E-15*A1^2/(A2*IF(B1="J",1,IF(B1="nukes",6276E10,IF(B1="twinkies",56E4,IF(B1="kWh",36E5,IF(B1="kg",299792E3^2,4184E9))))))&B1
```

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by substituting `299792E3^2` with `89876E12`  (Still accurate enough for question requirements.)
Divide all values by `1000` saves another 2:
`=40032E-19*A1^2/(A2*SWITCH(MID(B1,2,1),"u",6276E6,"w",56,"W",360,"g",89876E8,"i",4184E5,1E-4))&B1`

Comment: Hey, just want to throw it out there that the [`Switch()` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SWITCH-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e) is available to desktop copies of Excel, and was introduced with Office 2016.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby , <s>83</s> 82 bytes

```
->m,r,u{"#{40032E-18*m*m/r/[36E2,56,8987E9,1E-3,4184E6,6276E7][u.sum*3%71%6]} "+u}
```

Uses a custom hash to index a LUT for the units (`i * k mod m` formula). The numbers were found using brute-force.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 94 bytes

Takes Mass from `A1`, Radius from `B1`, Unit in `C1`.
Look up on `2*Code(Unit) + Length(Unit) modulo 11`.

```
=4.0032E-15*A1^2/B1/CHOOSE(MOD(2*CODE(C1)+LEN(C1),11),,4184E5,,,6276E6,1E-4,89876E8,360,56)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>59</s>  54 bytes

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to [@ChartZBelatedly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/chartz-belatedly)*

I just wanted to try another weird method to convert the units. But the rest of the code is probably badly golfed.

```
⁵OẒḄ%9ị56,4184ȷ5,8987ȷ9,360,0,6276ȷ6,ȷ-4
²÷÷2498ȷ11÷¢⁵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AW0Akv9qZWxsef//4oG1T@G6kuG4hCU54buLNTYsNDE4NMi3NSw4OTg3yLc5LDM2MCwwLDYyNzbItzYsyLctNArCssO3w7cyNDk4yLcxMcO3wqLigbX///8zLjNlMjP/MjQ0MDAwMP8ia2lsb3RvbnMi)

#### How?

We build a 'signature' of a unit string out of the primality of its ASCII codes. We interpret it as a binary value and apply a modulo to get the final index in the lookup table.

```
⁵OẒḄ%9ị[...]    - helper link to convert the unit to a hardcoded constant
⁵               - the 3rd input        e.g. "kilotons"
 O              - to ASCII codes       --> [107, 105, 108, 111, 116, 111, 110, 115]
  Ẓ             - is prime?            --> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
   Ḅ            - binary -> decimal    --> 128
    %9          - modulo 9             --> 2
      ị[...]    - get value from table --> 418400000

²÷÷2498ȷ11÷¢⁵   - main link taking the mass, the radius and the unit
²               - square the mass
 ÷              - divide by the radius
  ÷2498ȷ11      - divide by 2498e11
          ÷¢    - divide by the unit constant, invoking the helper link as a nilad
            ⁵   - append the unit
```

The helper link gives the following indices for each unit:

```
unit     | ASCII codes                     | is prime?       | bin -> dec | mod 9
---------+---------------------------------+-----------------+------------+------
J        | 74                              | 0               |      0     |   0
kilotons | 107,105,108,111,116,111,110,115 | 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 |    128     |   2
nukes    | 110,117,107,101,115             | 0,0,1,1,0       |      6     |   6
twinkies | 116,119,105,110,107,105,101,115 | 0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0 |     10     |   1
kWh      | 107,87,104                      | 1,0,0           |      4     |   4
kg       | 107,103                         | 1,1             |      3     |   3
```

Comment: The `[` and `]` are unnecessary. Additionally, the `⁴` can be removed and the `ÆP` has a 1 byte alias: `Ẓ`. Finally, if the number on the left of `ȷ` is `1`, it can be omitted. [-5 bytes](https://tio.run/##AW0Akv9qZWxsef//4oG1T@G6kuG4hCU54buLNTYsNDE4NMi3NSw4OTg3yLc5LDM2MCwwLDYyNzbItzYsyLctNArCssO3w7cyNDk4yLcxMcO3wqLigbX///8zLjNlMjP/MjQ0MDAwMP8ia2lsb3RvbnMi)

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly Thank you!